# Show only visible elements with each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="save" id="1">1</div>
<div class="save" id="2" style="display:none">2</div>
<div class="save" id="3">3</div>
<div class="save hide" id="4">4</div>
<div class="save" id="5">5</div>

.hide {
 display: none;
}

$('.save').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

This show me:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

but shold be:

```
1
3
5
```

What must I use to loop through each visible element?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Note that `this.id` will work where you've got `$(this).attr('id')` (but is more efficient at runtime and easier to read and type).

Comment: It's **well worth** spending an hour reading through [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It literally only takes that long, and it repays you multi-fold in a very short period of time.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [:visible](http://jqapi.com/#p=visible-selector) selector:

```
$('.save:visible').each(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
})
```

If you already have your `.save` elements, you can [`filter`](http://jqapi.com/#p=filter) them:

```
var $saves = $(".save");
$saves.filter(':visible').each(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.save:visible').each(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    })
```

Or

```
$('.save').each(function(){
      if( $(this).is(':visible') ) { //only if visible
           console.log($(this).attr('id'));
      }
      else { //only if hidden

      }
    })
```